# How to draw multiple line plots in a grid?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, line-plot

I have a dictionary whose values are consisted of dataframes. Every `df` has the same column names: `X1` and `X2`:

```
dic = {"a": df1, "b": df2, ..., "y": df25}
```

Now I want to draw line plots of these dataframes so that they will be in 5 rows and 5 columns. I want to get a visual as follows:

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest exploring subplot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea using [`matplotlib.pyplot.subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(5, 5)

for ax, (key, df) in zip(axes.flat, dic.items()):
    ax.set_title(key)
    ax.plot(df["X1"], df["X2"])
```

Comment: Dear @Anakhand, what about for this example:
 
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

for i in range(1,len(dic)+1):
    data = dic[i]
    n_clusters = range(1, 10)
    kmeans = [KMeans(n_clusters=j).fit(data) for j in n_clusters]
    SSD = [kmeans[j].inertia_ for j in range(len(kmeans))] # within-cluster sum of squares.
     
   fig, axes = plt.subplots(5, 5) 
   axes.plot(n_clusters, SSD)